# Disabling MultiSelect in Listbox without the conversion to a DropDownList

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to disable the multiselect in my listbox, but when I call removeAttr('multiple'), it turns my listbox into a dropdownlist. I don't want a dropdown, I want to keep the listbox. How can I adjust to make this happen? Thanks.

```
   @Html.ListBox("ListBoxName", new SelectList((IEnumerable<Epic>)ViewData["selectedestimate"], "Id", "Name", "EstimatedTime"), new {@class = "ListBoxClass", @style = "height: 325px;", @id = "epiclistbox"})


  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').removeAttr('multiple');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is set the `size` attribute to the `SELECT` element like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').removeAttr('multiple');
    $("select").attr("size", 5);
});
```